# Printing to the STDOUT vs writing to an output file directly

Tags: shell, programming, unix-philosophy

Is there any rule of thumb when the result of the program should be printed to the stdout by default, and when the more appropriate approach is to accept output file as one of the arguments and write to it? One can always redirect the stdout to a file.

I know that there are different programs, and for example it does not make sense to print to the stdout if the result is multiple files, not a single one. It also does not make sense to accept output file as an argument if the output of the program has temporary nature.

However, what about programs producing output that ultimately should be placed in a single file? Such programs can be further divided into programs accepting input from the stdin and the ones taking input from arguments.

Comment: This is pretty much done at the preference of the programmer - you'll likely only get opinion based answers to this question, instad of facts.

Comment: If you're not sure, why not print to `stdout` by default and add an optional `--output, -o` option?

Comment: @pLumo, as such approach would be redundant, one can always redirect stdout to file.

Comment: But then the user can decide, as obviously the programer (you) are not sure.

Comment: Depends on "user". What you provide to a sysadmin is very different to what you provide to a project manager user.

Comment: A general guideline for writing unix programs is: *Expect the output of every program to become the input to another, as yet unknown, program. Don't clutter output with extraneous information. Avoid stringently columnar or binary input formats. Don't insist on interactive input.* -- Doug Mcllroy, Bell System Technical Journal, 1978.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy

Comment: Obviously, if you have multiple output files, they can't all go to stdout.   But for one (or more) file(s) in, one-file-out, write it as a filter.  You'll thank yourself when you later realise you need to pipe the output into something else for further processing, or send it over an ssh connection to a remote system, or whatever.

Comment: Depends, depends. Any rules of thumb on what "should" be done are opinion based almost by definition. You could probably find examples going both ways, so it may well depend a bit on the exact use for the tool. Usually, it would be a good idea to allow both, even if redirections, process substitutions and pseudo-files like `/dev/stdin` allow for some leeway in switching between files and stdin or stdout.

Answer (score 2):

**A few practical examples:**

---

An application sending its output to stdout typically implies that the application works just fine with *any type* of recipient, it just sends a stream of data suitable also for a pipe or a socket. This is the very essence of Unix pipelines, so *if* there is any rule of thumb then this one is probably the best candidate.

---

On the other hand, though, a `-o <output-file-name>` option is typically preferred if the application rather *needs* to seek over its output.

Of course you can `lseek(2)` over stdout too (if it is indeed seekable), but that's conventionally unexpected behavior.

Naturally the same holds for input as well.

---

Redirecting from/to a file requires a shell. A dedicated option argument allows for not requiring a shell.

---

Redirecting from/to a file enables easy sharing of that file's position (if it is seekable) or that pipe/socket's connection among several applications, which can be a useful feat in shell scripting, such as in:

```bsh
{
    echo hello world
    head -c 10
    seq 10 | awk '{print "amazing text-manipulation of", $0}'
    dd bs=1024 count=1 seek=32
    echo farewell
} < /dev/random > recipient-file
```

Relying only on a `-o recipient-file` option (or `-i /dev/random`) would not allow that (so easily).

---

In some cases the opposite of the above may also hold: a `-o <output-file-name>` option allows for making that application's output *not* pollute stdout while sharing it with other applications, such as in:

```bsh
strace -o prog.strace output-producer > prog.output
```

The same holds for input, for having an application *not* consume a shared stdin.

```bsh
unwanted-consumer -i /dev/null desired-consumer
```

Relying only on stdin/stdout would require an additional layer of shell, like in:

```bsh
strace > prog.strace sh -c 'output-producer > prog.output'
```

or for stdin:

```bsh
unwanted-consumer 3<&0 < /dev/null sh -c 'desired-consumer <&3'
```

Apart from compactness/cleanliness of the command, and apart from requiring a shell at all, invoking a shell involves a somewhat different environment and you might need to adjust that for `output-producer` or `desired-consumer`, increasing the overall burden.

Answer (score 2):

If you can imagine the output of the program being used as input to another, and if the output is basically text, then defaulting to stdout lets the program be easily used as part of a pipeline.

On the other hand, if the output is usually binary, or very large (compared to inputs given), then it can make sense to ask for a filename by default, and refuse to print on the terminal unless explicitly asked.

For the first group, consider `grep`, `sort`, `cut` and such which work equally well as part of a pipeline feeding another program, and as giving output read directly by the user. Pretty much everyone knows they print to stdout and are used to redirecting the output to a file if they want that.

For the second, consider e.g. `convert` from ImageMagick, which can convert and process image files. It takes the input and output filenames on the command line. Here, it's rarer for the image file to be used as part of a pipeline, and in practice, one never wants a JPEG or PNG dumped to their terminal, so here it makes sense to do it that way.

When taking filename arguments, it may be a good idea to let `-` stand for stdin or stdout, provided that you document this. It's a rather common custom, and saves the user from having to use something like `/dev/stdin` instead. (And that could fail in some systems.)

Doing what other tools do is good in that it leaves less room for surprises. Unless of course your use case is different enough that copying others doesn't make sense.